# Fused Location Provider - location updates by displacement not working

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I have an android application which will track location from background.i am using fused location api with following configuration

```
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(60*1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(60*1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I need location updates only if device moves.Sometimes everything works perfectly.But sometimes i receive location updates even if device in stationary.

Why this issue happens? If i set displacement,do i need to set interval and fastest interval? Is this issue related to google play service version?

Comment: Can you show how you call the method `requestLocationUpdates` ?

Answer (score 0):

It will update your location every 60 seconds if your mobile moves or not beaus of your give interval duration.

Comment: do you know how to get location only if device moves?

Comment: You have to use this method                                                       '@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
'

Comment: But it will very sensitive. It will update location on small movement

Comment: i think i should get rid of time settings by set interval to max time. So if i moved i get location. I just build with this configuration. lets see what happens

Comment: i think increasing the time will cause location update to particular time. it wont help

Answer (score 0):

Request your location updates using a GoogleApiClient e.g. like this and use Toasts to verify your implementation:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 5000;
    long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 0;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mlocationListener);
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES! mLastLocation!=null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude = " + latitude + "\nLongitude = " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here you would be able to parametrize your Location requests with the variables `LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE` and `LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME` (in milliseconds)

You would need of course the LocationListener object `mLocationListener` that your GoogleApiClient `mGoogleApiClient` needs to get the last known / current location and a Location object (I called it `mLastLocation`) where to store it. eg.:

```
private Location mLastLocation;
LocationListener mlocationListener = new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation=location;

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you likely need is the [PendingIntent version](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) of FusedLocationProviderApi. This method is suited for the background use cases, more specifically for receiving location updates, even when the app has been killed by the system.

Comment: location via PendingIntent you will only get location in background when your app or some to app will try to fetch location.Eles you will not get location update in background